# Deploying a UDDI service

Tags: service

We've been tasked with deploying an oldschool application that **needs** [UDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration) discovery to consume web services. Last I checked there's no public UDDI interfaces available (Systinet, Microsoft and IBM all used to offer them but they're long gone by now).

Does anyone have any experience or guidance they can offer regarding deploying an internal UDDI service? I'm aware of [jUDDI](http://ws.apache.org/juddi/) but I've never administered Tomcat and I have a phobia of Java (long story).

We're almost entirely an x64 Windows shop, but I'm happy to fire up an Ubuntu or FreeBSD VM to host the service if required. We already have Systinet as it's required by the app, which has UDDI integration but don't seem to support hosting a UDDI.

Comment: Can you reformulate "WHAT" you need to accomplish before "HOW"?

Comment: @vgv8 - as mentioned we have an old application that can only consume and publish web services through the use of the UDDI protocol. UDDI is long dead, but you can roll your own UDDI server if need be. UDDI is the only option we have, as the software is no longer maintaned by its original developers.

Comment: So, you need UDDI service for external (not yours) webservices "registration"? Or you need both consume (publish references) external webservices and publish your own webservices (also registreing, i.e. consuming it in your UDDI)? Or you do not need "both" (really here are more than 4 combinations of cases)

Comment: @vgv8 - both. We need to publish web services to the UDDI so that the application can consume them.